# How to Fill Nested Model Information in a Popbox for Rails 3.2?

Tags: jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms

I have a Request model and a nested Keyword model in my system. I want to click 'Add Keyword' button or link in Request index page and want to fill the Keyword informations in a popbox. I don't want to open a new page.

At first, I have used Ryan Bates' [Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised). But my models are very specific and thus they make the page very long. I don't want to make page so much vertical. I just don't want to scroll up-down all the time.

I've looked around so much, there are a lot of questions here, too. But I didn't find the specific solution. Can you help me, please? Thanks.